# Regex to replace the dot inside curly braces?

Tags: regex

Is it possible to replace the dot with a underscore but just inside curly braces using only regex ?

```
eg. a.b.c={{c.d.f}} 
    after the replace it should look like
    a.b.c={{c_d_f}}
```

The curly braces are always balanced and there will always be two open curly braces and two closed ones.

Comment: which programming language?

Comment: specify the programming language along with all possible assumptions like balanced brackets and whether the content should be inside double brackets only or can it be in single bracket?

Comment: @ritesht93 Regex in general, it can any text editor that has Regex ability eg. Notepad++.

Comment: @panagdu There is no regex in general. Regular expression engines come in different flavours and with different feature sets. Also a regular expression itself cannot *replace* something, they are just meant to *match* a pattern. Poor question! I wonder who upvoted that...

Comment: @hek2mgl Thank you very much for your reply. You don't have to hate me for asking something "poorly" in StackOverflow. Right now I'm using IntellijJIdea and I have used Notepad++ for simple search/replace with Regexp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this lookahead regex for search:

```
\.(?=[^{}]*\})
```

Lookahead `(?=[^{}]*\})` asserts that there is a `}` ahead after 0 or more non `{` and non `}` characters.

and replace by `_`

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qD2rE7/1)

Comment: This does not check if a dot is *inside* paired curly braces.

Comment: This is assuming `{` and `}` are balanced and there is no escaping.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\G` like (assuming `.` inside only `{{` and no nesting)

```
(?:(\{\{)|\G(?!\A))([^.}]*)[.]
```

and replace with

```
\1\2_
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aN9mM9/1)**

Answer (score 0):

If u assume there is one character between dots use: 
Search:({{.).(.).(.}})
Replace with:\1_\2_\3
If one or more:
Search:({{.+).(.+).(.+}})
With same replace